# Can a clock be set in VHDL using an internal oscillator?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to learn VHDL, an am writing a simple transmitter for serial data. However, I encountered a problem - I need a clock to run it, and the datasheet for my FPGA (MAX II) says this:

> Output of the internal oscillator for MAX II devices: 3.3-5.5 MHz

So there is no way to reliably set the frequency of the internal FPGA oscillator? And if there is, how do you do it efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Most FPGA boards provide at least one - often several - crystal oscillators of different frequencies, and many FPGAs provide clock modules (DCM, PLL)  to multiply or divide those frequencies to get the frequency you need.

Comment: @BrianDrummond but as I stated, my FPGA appears to have an oscillator with a frequency range. A quote from the manual: "This is determined
only by the CPLD, and is in the range of 3.3 MHz to 5.5 MHz." I have found no information on how to actually determine that frequency.

Comment: Then I believe you don't. It's somewhere between those values, depending on voltage, temperature, and the FPGA process parameters. As you quoted : "determined only by the CPLD". If you need a specific frequency, supply it yourself.

Comment: [Using the Internal Oscillator in Altera MAX Series, App Note 496](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/an/an496.pdf). The frequency will be silicon process dependent.  The frequency can't be set.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1155120 thank you.

Comment: The App Note was found by googling for block quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to set the frequency of the internal oscillator. It's most likely an RC oscillator built into the die, so its frequency will depend heavily on silicon process variations and temperature.

If you need something more precise, it'll need to be external to the CPLD.